# nested for loop logic error with time logic error

Tags: c++, nested-loops

The output only displays time from 7 to 11:59. Its suppose to be from noon to midnight. Its a logic error but I can't find a way to correct it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int hour,min;

    for (hour=0;hour<=11;hour+=1)
    {    
        for (min=0;min<=59;min++)
        {
            if (min<10)
                cout<<hour<<":"<<"0"<<min<<endl;
            else
                cout<<hour<<":"<<min<<endl;
        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the first 7 hours haven't just run off the console? Try outputting to a file instead.

Comment: You are missing a bracket - I am lazy - please post code that I can compile.

Comment: You can use your shell to help you: `myexecutable > output.txt`

Comment: @Adrian, he is also missing the definition of `main()`, and some include statements, and he has not read http://sscce.org unfortunately

Comment: @DavidGrayson True ;-) hence my comment of `please post code that I can compile.`

Comment: @DavidGrayson your link is broken for me - expected?

Comment: @AdrianCornish, http://www.isup.me/sscce.org

Comment: @chris down for me too - BGP problem somewhere (no doubt with my ISP <sigh>)

Answer (score 2):

The Windows console is configured to show at most 300 lines of scrollback (output) by default.

7 is 5 hours behind 12, and 5*60 = 300. Therefore, you are (most likely) seeing the limit of your scrollback buffer.

Increase the size of your scrollback (right click on the command prompt icon, select properties->layout, set the scrollback to something higher like 9999), or write your output to a file. You will see the right output.

Comment: I am in basic computer science in college. Most of the stuff you refer to we haven't gone over. The directions say there is a logic error and I have to add lines to fix it. @nneonneo

Comment: I think this is the answer to the question. I ran the code on XCode (Mac) and it's working fine (prints `0:00` until `11:59`)

Comment: @NiaBoone: It looks like you fixed the logic error. Now you just have to use a bigger scrollback buffer to see all of your output.

Comment: I use Microsoft visual studios 2010 and I take basic computer science in college so I have to use what we have learned. I don't know what lines to add to be able to see hours from noon to midnight. The directions say to add lines. @nneonneo

Comment: Like I said, right-click the command prompt icon and adjust the size of your scrollback buffer. When you run the program it will be fine. See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/commandpromptoptions.mspx?mfr=true for instructions (you care about setting "Screen Buffer Size", as in step 7)

Comment: I have windows 7 not XP , the directions are for XP @nneonneo

Comment: ...have you tried them? The command prompt hasn't changed that much.

Comment: @NiaBoone, You could use a winapi function to do it as well ;) Anyway, right click the title bar, click `Properties`, and on the `Layout` tab, adjust the `Screen Buffer Size->Height`.

Comment: how many times would the inner loop and outer loop execute? I believe the outer is 10 @nneonneo

Comment: The outer loop executes 12 times...0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11. It stops when `hour = 12`.

Comment: so the inner loop executes 60 times? Is the if else statement included in that execution? @nneonneo